# PySpark - How to sort by the value inside the ResultIterable?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm building an RDD:

```
kk = preRatings.filter(lambda a:a.rating>0).map(lambda b:(b.user,(b.product,b.rating)))
```

How can I sort by the rating value(desc) and get top 10 results with the format(user,(product,rating)?

BTW, I'm referring this scala code and don't know what the author is trying to do inside the `case`

```
preRatings 
 .filter(_.rating > 0) 
 .map(rating => (rating.user,(rating.product, rating.rating))) 
 .groupByKey() 
 .map{ case (uid,recs) => 
          UserRecs(uid,recs.toList.sortWith(_._2 >_._2)
          .take(10)
          .map(x => Recommendation(x._1,x._2))) 
 }.toDF()
```

specifically, this line:

```
recs.toList.sortWith(_._2 >_._2)
```

What does this mean by comparing with the same _2?

Comment: " __2 " mean second element inside tuple .. toList.sortWith(_._2 >_._2).take(10) this basically means sorty by 2nd element and take top 10 values from the sorted result.

Comment: @kavetiraviteja Thanks for your reply but what I don't understand is why comparising ._2>._2, like 10>10, this will never be true